# Data For Object Detection

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, yolo, yolov8

I am training a machine model (YOLO or similar) to detect objects (gas cylinders) in garbage piles. Is it better to train with unlabeled data of isolated gas canisters (ex if you google "gas canister") or with labeled photos of gas canisters in garbage piles? Or both.

Would it be worth training on unlabeled pics of isolated objects to detect them in clutter?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3rJq.jpg)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts1k2.jpg)

I am trying to create an accurate model to detect gas canisters in piles of garbage

Answer (score 0):

**ML is about experimenting**. What have you tried and what are the results you have received? Without this information, there can be only general recommendations.

It is beneficial to train a model on a sufficient amount of good-labeled variety of data, which is **representative** of your target scenario. Look at your target scenario data: *the variety of the size of the target objects, the size of the images themselves, lightning, perspective, background, etc*. Make your training dataset as representative as you can.

You can add less representative data like your first example to enlarge and diversify the dataset, you may need to use **data augmentation** techniques to make the dataset even more varied.

If you want your model to *detect* objects - not only classify images by the existence of the target objects but localize these objects, - label the data in a way necessary for the **object detection** task.

In case you already have some amount of data ready for training, it can be reasonable to train the model as it is and see the results as a starting point. It will be useful for the assessment of the situation and for evaluating the performance of the next training experiments.

Use **pre-trained** model weights if you can.

For YOLO, see the [Tips for Best Training Results](https://docs.ultralytics.com/yolov5/tutorials/tips_for_best_training_results/).

Having a bunch of compact not too time-consuming experiments will help you figure out what works for your problem solution and what not to waste time on.